# Apparently there is a conflict between errorPlacement and highlight in the JQuery Validatin Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a dialog box with one textbox and two spinner:

```
<div id="dialogCategory" title="Categoria">
    <form id="formAddCategory">
        <div class="ui-widget" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px">
            <label for="txtCategoryName">Nome categoria:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtCategoryName" name="txtCategoryName" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" size="10"/>
        </div>
        <div  style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px">
            <label for="spinTeamNumber">Numero di squadre:</label>
            <input id="spinTeamNumber" name="spinTeamNumber" style="display: inline-block" size="3" maxlength="3">
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px">
            <label for="spinCatMinutes">Minutaggio giornaliero:</label>
            <input id="spinCatMinutes" name="spinCatMinutes" style="display: inline-block" size="3" maxlength="3">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I click the "OK" button I make a validation of the fields using jQuery Validation Plugin.

I modified the errorPlacement function to differentiate the behaviour between two different controls. I needed that in the textbox and in the spinner the error were placed in a different position.
This worked.

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
    console.log(element);
    if ($(element).hasClass("ui-spinner-input")) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

After that, I needed to differentiate the highlight elements between textbox and spinner. To do that I introduced the two callback functions "highlight" and "unhighlight".

```
highlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if ($(element).hasClass("ui-spinner-input")) {
        var temp = $(element).parent();
        temp.addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
    }
},
unhighlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if ($(element).hasClass("ui-spinner-input")) {
        var temp = $(element).parent();
        temp.removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
    }
}
```

it not enters in the function "errorPlacement" any more.

Why?

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the problem.  Where are the rest of your `.validate()` options? What are the validation rules?  How are the spinners created?

Comment: **WHICH** `label` are you trying to select with `.find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")`?  Your `label` or the dynamically created `label` for the error message?  They look identical in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently there is a conflict between errorPlacement and highlight...

The `errorPlacement` callback is for "placing" the error labels into your layout.  Once that's done, the plugin simply toggles them.

That being said, you're creating your own conflict by adding the error class to the `label` element...

```
$(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
```

By default, the plugin uses `label` elements as the container for the error messages.  I can't even tell which `label` elements you're trying to select here... yours or the labels created by the plugin?

In other words, with the `error` class applied, your `label` elements look *identical* to the dynamically created `label` elements used for error messages.  Now the plugin cannot tell them apart, so it takes over the first one it finds... yours.

Changing the default error container from a `label` into a `span` using the `errorElement` option, clears that up.

```
errorElement: "span"
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/199qtuh4/3/**

With this solution, it does not matter which ones you are trying to target.  Targeting the `span` works too...

```
$(element.form).find("span[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/199qtuh4/2/**

Or if you really wanted to select both...

```
$(element.form).find("[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/199qtuh4/5/**

---

Without being entirely sure exactly which `label` elements you want to select, you *might* be able to simplify the code by using a `.next()`.  Then you can keep the default error message element as `label`.

```
 $(element).next("label").addClass(errorClass);
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/199qtuh4/4/**

The point of this last demo is to show you that a conflict can be resolved through more accurate DOM traversal and selection.